# Is it possible to make a Hibernate Query skip bad records in a multi-record query?

Tags: java, hibernate

I have an object that does validation in its setters. For example:

```
class Employee {
   private String name;
   public void setName(String theName) {
     if (theName.contains("*")) {
       throw new IllegalArgumentException("You can't have an asterisk in a name!");
     }
     name = theName
   }
}
```

When a Hibernate query attempts to instantiate the object with invalid data (such as an `Employee` with name "John Smith*"), the `IllegalArgumentException` causes the entire query to fail. For this particular application -- loading up a cache -- the ideal behavior would be for Hibernate to trap the exception, reject the record, and return a list of objects that did not throw any kind of exception during initialization.

I am aware of a number of alternate solutions:

- Setting up Hibernate with [direct field access](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t272767-direct-field-access-in-hibernate.html), bypassing setters
- Instead of throwing exceptions in setters, mark objects as invalid and then filter them out of the List that comes back from `org.hibernate.Query.list()`, or save validation for after `list()` returns.
- Guarantee cleanliness of db data (if only this was within my power!)

My preference is to allow objects to continue to throw exceptions from setters, and to avoid doing post-processing on Hibernate results, and to avoid introduce new validation lifecycle steps for Hibernate-instantiated objects. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no such silent error ignoring in Hibernate. What about filtering such records at SQL/HQL level? Something like:

```
...
WHERE name NOT LIKE "%*%"
```

I know Hibernate can apply such filter automatically to every query. Alternative approach is to have a (materialized) view.

Of course this approach introduced some duplication (in general rules in `Employee` class must precisely match those in SQL), but it still seems the cleanest way.

Comment: even though this should work, seems an inefficient solution. Doing validation in the client, before the query even hits the would be much cheaper.

Comment: Though this would work for the specific example posed, it's possible for object setters to have complicated validation logic that would be infeasible to push into the HQL clause. Imagine a setter that is doing validation on the results of some complicated mathematical function that is not supported in HQL.